# Play audio files with FireMonkey on OSX

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

What is the best way to play audio files such as MP3 or Wav on OSX using Firemonkey? It seems  this is not possible using the oficial libraries (first release of Delphi XE2). Im fairly new developing on OSX and I don't know much. I'm guessing I'll have to play around with FPC and Objective-C on OSX to work with the OpenAL Framework, if so, what you people recommed? is there an easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: I guess that is the "official" way to put it, but if you see it from the functional point of view there is no way to deploy an OSX application without Firemonkey (in delphi XE2). At this point the strongest part of FireMonkey is without doubt the GUI Framework but the FM implementation also brings lots of non visual components. Audio fits in the multimedia category wich is the way I see FM and not just a GUI Framework. I guess it could be a FPC topic too but for me is the whole tech integration what it counts. But you are right it's not what's should be it's what it is.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[BASS](http://dev.ixchels.net/resources/soundlib)** library.

Comment: Thank you very much!, I sucessfully implement the BASS libraries using a Firemonkey App. I had to make minor modifications to the dynamic API to work with FM.